# ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads() not working in if controller

Tags: groovy, jmeter

[image]

as the title says, the "FINISH" sample is not hit

My script in "If Controller" is `${__groovy("${ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads()}".equals("4"))}`

[image]

**OK I FOUND WORKAROUND FOR THIS**

1. When threads run, I set total threads in var "NumThreads"
   [image]
2. The If Controller to check the last thread finished
   [image]
3. The result: only the sampler of the last thread in "Thread Group"
   [image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two strings which are not equal so your condition will never return true.

You need to amend the condition to look like:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads() == 4,)}
```

More information:

- [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)
- [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)
- [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

Answer (score 0):

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy

According to documentation it should be like this

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads().equals(4))}
```